# Creating Windows Terminal keyboard shortcut for Windows Store App

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a keyboard shortcut "CTRL + ALT + T" for Windows Terminal from the command line. I'm assuming there's some built-in Powershell command for accessing packages installed through Windows Store where I can simply change settings, like "shortcuts". 
*NOTE: This isn't the same as right-clicking an application and choosing "shortcuts". In order to do this with Windows 10 Store apps, you have to go to the shortcuts folder, right-click the app, and add the shortcut there.*
I have had to do this on many Windows 10 installations and I just want a quicker way to accomplish this.

Comment: For what its worth, I have WT pinned to my Taskbar as the first item and I use [Win]+1 or [Shift]+[Win]+1 to launch WT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "Terminal", I assume you mean the CMD prompt, but this applies to *any* Windows application.

1. Right-click the Desktop, and select *New > Shortcut*.
2. In the *location of the item*, type or paste the following, or the location of any application:

   C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
3. Accept the default name or type another.
4. Click *Finish*.
5. Right-click the new shortcut and select *Properties*.
6. Set the *Shortcut key* by pressing the corresponding key combination, e.g, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

[image: Shortcut to CMD]

7. Click *OK*.

**This shortcut can be copied to other PC's, but may need to be re-registered.** Windows now restricts the folders from which a keyboard shortcut works. You can put the shortcut (.lnk) file on the *Desktop* or in either of the following folders:

```
  C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

**To re-register the keyboard shortcut**, *after* moving the shortcut, right-click, change the shortcut key to *another*, *Apply*, change it back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, and *Apply*, again.

Answer (score 0):

This is more specific to Windows Terminal, not *just* cmd.exe.

Open Windows Terminal:

1. Settings -> Actions
2. Set a keyboard shortcut for "Show/Hide The Terminal Window" (I use ctrl+f12)
3. Done.

You can also set it to minimize tray, so that its not in your taskbar unless its focused. I personally then use PowerToys (Keyboard Manager) to set the F11 key universally to forward to Crtl+F12, for one click opening and minimizing.